# What is the equivalent of div in HTML in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I want to create an element in JavaFX to which i'll be able to add child elements,change background color and position.So far i stumbled across GridPane and Rectangle,but couldn't find any good documentation on any of them.So which JavaFX element is closest to div in HTML?

Comment: Use simple _Pane_  o r _AnchorPane_ can make you free when you add children nodes.

Comment: Don't start `JavaFX` with `HTML` in your mind. Learn the language as if you don't know anything about coding.

Comment: Also, I suggest you start with [`Gluon Scenebuilder`](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/) after you finish learning what jewelsea shared.

Comment: I consider the javadocs to be a pretty good documentation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here there is the official documentation 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm